# Proof in field theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ordered-fields

Im having trouble with this question:
$\mathbb F$ is an ordered field
Prove that for all $x,y\in\mathbb F$ , $xy > 0 \iff ((x<0 \land y<0)\lor(x>0 \land y>0))$

I managed to prove that right side implies left side, but I couldnt manage to prove vice versa

Thanks.

Comment: More specifically you're considering an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) so you will need to use the order axioms of such a field.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? (Also, are you working with an *ordered* field?)

Comment: I managed to prove that right side implies left side, but I couldnt manage to prove vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Trichotomy Law, for any $x\in F$
$$
x>0\lor x=0\lor x<0
$$
If $x=0$ or $y=0$, then $xy=0$. So 
$$
xy>0\implies x\ne0 \land y\ne 0
$$
If $x>0$ and $y<0$, then $-y>0$ and 
$$
-xy=x(-y)>0\quad \text{and so}\quad xy<0
$$
Likewise if $x<0$ and $y>0$, then $xy<0$. Thus
$$
xy > 0 \implies (x<0 \land y<0)\lor(x>0 \land y>0)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try proving the two statements:

1. $(x<0\wedge y<0)\vee(x>0\wedge y>0)\ \implies\ xy>0$
2. $(x<0\wedge y>0)\vee(x>0\wedge y<0)\ \implies\ xy<0$